# Basex XQL merging content with same tag name, regardless of location in document

Tags: xml, xpath, basex, flwor

For example, given XML:

```
<root>
    <item>
        <id>111</id>
        <description>aisle 12, shelf 3</description>
        <description>inside the box</description>
    </item>
</root>
```

I would like the result:

```
<root>
    <item>
        <id>111</id>
        <description>aisle 12, shelf 3 inside the box</description>
    </item>
</root>
```

But the node may have any name, and be at any level.
I would like the same query to work with different XML, as long as the tag is repeated:

```
<root>
    <item>
        <id>112</id>
        <attributes>
            <author>Joe Smith</author>
            <author>Arthur Clarke</author>
            <author>Jeremiah Wright</author>
        </attributes>
    </item>
</root>
```

Output:

```
<root>
    <item>
        <id>112</id>
        <attributes>
            <author>Joe Smith Arthur Clarke Jeremiah Wright</author>
        </attributes>
    </item>
</root>
```

Is this possible with BaseX ?
If not, can we do this given a known element (for example, only for /root/item/attributes/author)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensuring to only merge directly following siblings complicates things a little bit. I added some comments on how the code is working below.

```
let $xml := document{<root>
    <item>
        <id>112</id>
        <attributes>
            <author>Joe Smith</author>
            <author>Arthur Clarke</author>
            <author>Jeremiah Wright</author>
            <foo/>
            <author>Donald Duck</author>
        </attributes>
    </item>
</root>}
return
  (: Use an XQuery Update transformation :)
  copy $copy := $xml
  modify (
    (: Loop over all leaves (only containing text nodes. :)
    (: This might have to be adjusted if you want to merge arbitrary nodes. :)
    for $leaf in $copy//*[not(*)]
    (: Where the preceding node is not of the same name :)
    (: (as it will be merged anyway) :)
    where not($leaf/preceding-sibling::*[1 and name(.) eq name($leaf)])
    (: Now find following siblings... :)
    let $siblings := $leaf/following-sibling::*[
      (: ... of the same name ... :)
      name(.) eq name($leaf) and
      (: ... and that do not have a node with another name in-between :)
      not(preceding-sibling::*[name(.) != name($leaf) and $leaf << .])
    ]
    return (
      (: Merge text contents into $leaf :)
      replace value of node $leaf with string-join(($leaf, $siblings), ' '),
      (: And delete all others :)
      delete nodes $siblings
    )
  )
  return $copy
```